# Text field does not pass data through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, webforms

I have been playing with the AJAX function i found online and the thing that puzzle me was that using a drop list, i was able to send the value to my search page whereas using a text field i am having difficulty.

```
<form name="search" action="" method="POST">
Search: <input type="text" name="find" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="showUser()"/>
</form>
```

These are the two form that i am using. The one at the bottom works whereas the one at the top is the one i am having problem with. Any idea why is this the case ?

```
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","sfindme.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you notice that one of those function calls is missing the argument, as in the `this.value` part that is passed as `str` ?

Comment: yes i did. I was trying with and without `this.value` It doesnt make a difference.

Comment: Is the form submitting? A submit button would generally submit the form and reload the page, at which point your javascript is lost.

Comment: Nope. The text field is not submitting whereas the selecting form is working

Comment: But surely when you click the submit button, the form is submitting, at least that is what is supposed to happen as there is nothing preventing it? Try just changing the type from `submit` to `button`, add the `this.value` argument, and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the page to reload; then instead of a submit button, use a simple button that triggers the call to the `showUser` function. So your code should be :

```
<form name="search" action="" method="POST">
Search: <input type="text" id="find" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="showUser(document.getElementById('find'))"/>
</form>

<div id ="txtHint">
</div>

<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","sfindme.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However by doing what you have suggested. It result in the page to reload.

Comment: @user2691544 I have edited the answer, now the page does not reload. Hope this helps ! :)